Z-scores (heatmap) and statistics with replicates and outliers
My group performed a biological assay.The assay was performed for 6 different cell culture conditions (columns) and for 6 genes (rows). However, it was also performed 5 times (5 replicates) per each gene.
An example of our data:



Genes
Condition 1
Condition 2




Gene 1 replicate 1
0.22
120


Gene 1 replicate 2
0.34
122


Gene 1 replicate 3
0.45
119


Gene 1 replicate 4
0.33
34


Gene1 replicate 5
0.55
90


Gene 2 replicate 1
12
0.1


Gene 2 replicate 2
19.3
0.45


Gene 2 replicate 3
23.4
NA


Gene 2 replicate 4
11.7
0.89


Gene 2 replicate 5
12.4
0.1



And so on...for 6 genes and 6 conditions. Unfortunately we also have 2 NA values (for 2 conditions in gene 5 replicate 3, which doesn't mean the value is 0, it's just undetectable by the machine (below detectable value).
I have already posted a question on stackoverflow about how to perform the analysis (z-score and heatmap) with R, and a very friendly user also suggested to ask here for a more statistical insight.
The final heatmap will represent the changes of these genes expression in the different conditions. Basically in the end we want to compare the conditions based on their gene expressions, and maybe a pattern. In the end we would like to state "this cell culture condition has this gene pattern, which is different from the one of that cell culture condition".
Our problem number 1 is the outlier. Replicate number 4 is in every condition an outlier. Should we exclude it? If so we would only have 4 replicates for the statistical analysis (ex. correlation etc.).
Because of the outlier I am confused whether the z-score should be calculated with the mean, or if in this case we can use the median. Knowing very well that it would skew the result. Is it statistically correct to calculate each z-score and then pull them together based on the gene (ex. pull together all z-scores of gene1 condition 1 replicates)?
Problem number 2 are the two missing value. How can I still use the data but ignoring those values? How will it affect my statistical analysis?
Moreover, do you have any suggestion on the clustering and distance methods to be used for heatmapping these data?
At last, we were thinking of performing Wilcoxon test (non-parametric paired samples test) and 1 sample t-test for the actual statistical analysis of the data. We were suggested to use both because the data are a bit strange, and having both analysis will reinforce the result.

The difference between your individual groups is so large that I would recommend against any test, since there clearly is a difference. Wilcoxon test would be extremely underpowered as it ignores  the size of differences and a t-test is maybe appropriate on the log-scale, but i wouldn't want to use it. Also you should question what you are trying to test and keep in mind multiple comparison.
You have to little data to delete outliers and replicate 4 doesn't even look that bad.
If NA represents a value too small to detect I'd impute an appropriately small value like 0.05.
I don't understand what use a z-Scores would have here other the raw data. When in doubt just stick with raw.
A heatmap would be fine but I think you can just show individual data-points, slighty jittered to avoid overlap. It would be much clearer:

library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(Genes = c("Gene 1 replicate 1", "Gene 1 replicate 2", 
                         "Gene 1 replicate 3", "Gene 1 replicate 4", "Gene 1 replicate 5", 
                         "Gene 2 replicate 1", "Gene 2 replicate 2", "Gene 2 replicate 3", 
                         "Gene 2 replicate 4", "Gene 2 replicate 5"), Condition.1 = c(0.22, 
                                                                                      0.34, 0.45, 0.33, 0.55, 12, 19.3, 23.4, 11.7, 12.4), Condition.2 = c(120, 
                                                                                                                                                           122, 119, 34, 90, 0.1, 0.45, NA, 0.89, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -10L))
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Condition.1, Condition.2), names_to = "Condition") %>% 
  mutate(value = replace_na(value, 0.05), # value below detection
         repli = substring(Genes, 8), 
         Genes = substring(Genes, 1, 6), 
         replicate_4 = (repli == "replicate 4")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Genes, y = value, color = replicate_4, shape = replicate_4)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0, size = 2) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.05, 0.1*10^(0:5)), labels = c("below\ndetection", 0.1*10^(0:5))) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~Condition, ncol = 1)

#ggsave("cv.png")

